# href returns undefined with .attr(), .prop(), .each() etc but is able to return the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

```
const results = $(".someclass")
    .map((index, element) => {
        const hrefValue = $(element).find("a").prop("href");
        // or...
        const hrefValue2 = $(element).find("a").attr("href");
      
        return { hrefValue };
    })
    .get();
    console.log(results);
```

console log gives me what I expect. (The value of the property `href`). e.g. `https://www.google.com`

But if I try to modify the href value (which, according to type of, is a 'string') with any string methods, for example

`const hrefValue = $(element).find("a").prop("href").toUpperCase();`

I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

Everything I have researched points to jquery returning undefined, but that's not the case here I don't think, because I do get the value returned. I am just unable to modify it along the way with string methods, and that is the part I am unsure of, as to why.

EDIT:
It is puppeteer so it is scraping, but here is the gist of the HTML:

```
<div className="someclass">
    <a href="https://www.google.com>google</a>
</div>
```

I am able to return the value, and the `type of` is 'string', but if I try to modify it with string methods, I get the undefined error.

SOLUTION:
credit to @epascarello for the solution. The first object in a scraped puppeteer array is indeed blank. That is why it was giving the undefined error.

Once I placed a `.slice(1) in front of the .map(), then the results displayed properly in the console without the undefined error.

Comment: Why are you mapping elements? That's not typical for jQuery.

Comment: You've shown Puppeteer markup. jQuery acts on rendered HTML. Can we assume that `className` actually appears in the browser as `class`?

Comment: @isherwood It is a common use case and says it in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Sounds like one of the links does not have an href. Simple debugging with console.log() and point you to the link with the problem.

Comment: I think this may be the case. Puppeteer returns the first object in the array with blank values for each property. I am going to test your theory and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: credit to @epascarello for the solution. The first object in a scraped puppeteer array is indeed blank. That is why it was giving the undefined error.

Once I placed a `.slice(1) in front of the .map(), then the results displayed properly in the console without the undefined error.

Comment: A more robust approach would be to check for the element or value regardless of index.